# jaxb, xsd import not recognized

Tags: java, maven, jaxb, xsd, maven-jaxb2-plugin

I have a big problem with jaxb plugin. I have a project A where I have src/main/resources/xsd/common.xsd file. In this project I use cxf-xjc-plugin
to generate java classes. I have also my episod file under src/main/resources/META-INF called sun-jaxb.episode

Next, I have project B which has maven dependency to project A. In this project I have src/main/resources/catalog.txt

```
PUBLIC "http://www.some_path" "maven:GROUP_ID_OF_PROJECT_A:ARTIFACT_ID_OF_PROJECT_A:jar::!/common.xsd"
```

In project B I have pom file with jaxb plugin

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <extension>true</extension>
                <episodes>
                    <episode>
                        <groupId>GROUP_ID_OF_PROJECT_A</groupId>
                        <artifactId>ARTIFACT_ID_OF_PROJECT_A</artifactId>
                    </episode>
                </episodes>
                <catalogs>
                    <catalog>src/main/resources/catalog.txt</catalog>
                </catalogs>
            </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

Next, I have in project B

```
 src/main/resources/other/xsd my main.xsd
```

file where I use type definitions from common.xsd

I have xmlns:cmns="http://www.some_path"  // it is the same as in catalog.txt
 and

```
<xs:import namespace="http://www.some_path"/>
```

but the problem is that I get error undefined simple or complex type , because it doesn't recognize cmns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use this plugin to solve the public import of the xsd

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <args>
            <arg>-Xannotate</arg>
            <arg>-Xnamespace-prefix</arg>
            <arg>-nv</arg>
        </args>
        <extension>true</extension>
        <forceRegenerate>true</forceRegenerate>
        <bindingDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/xjb</bindingDirectory>
        <bindingIncludes>
            <include>*.xjb</include>
        </bindingIncludes>
        <schemas>
            <schema>
                <fileset>
                    <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/xsd</directory>
                    <includes>
                        <include>*.xsd</include>
                    </includes>
                </fileset>
            </schema>
            <schema>
                <dependencyResource>
                    <groupId>groupID</groupId>
                    <artifactId>artifactID</artifactId>
                    <resource>target.xsd</resource>
                </dependencyResource>
            </schema>

        </schemas>
        <episodes>
            <episode>
                <groupId>groupID</groupId>
                <artifactId>artifactID</artifactId>
            </episode>
        </episodes>
        <debug>true</debug>
        <verbose>true</verbose>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
                <version>0.6.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb2-basics-annotate</artifactId>
                <version>0.6.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb2-namespace-prefix</artifactId>
                <version>1.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

---

**Plugin for pom.xml of project A**

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.1</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>generate</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <args>
                <arg>-Xannotate</arg>
                <arg>-nv</arg>
                <arg>-Xnamespace-prefix</arg>
            </args>
            <extension>true</extension>
            <schemas>
                <schema>
                    <fileset>
                        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/xsd/</directory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>A.xsd</include>
                        </includes>
                    </fileset>
                </schema>
            </schemas>
            <bindingDirectory>src/main/resources/xjb</bindingDirectory>
            <bindingIncludes>
                <include>*.xjb</include>
            </bindingIncludes>
            <debug>true</debug>
            <verbose>true</verbose>
            <forceRegenerate>true</forceRegenerate>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
                    <version>0.6.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb2-basics-annotate</artifactId>
                    <version>0.6.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb2-namespace-prefix</artifactId>
                    <version>1.1</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

**Plugin for pom.xml of project B**

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.1</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>generate</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <args>
                <arg>-Xannotate</arg>
                <arg>-Xnamespace-prefix</arg>
                <arg>-nv</arg>
            </args>
            <extension>true</extension>
            <forceRegenerate>true</forceRegenerate>
            <bindingDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/xjb</bindingDirectory>
            <bindingIncludes>
                <include>*.xjb</include>
            </bindingIncludes>
            <schemas>
                <schema>
                    <fileset>
                        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/xsd/</directory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>B.xsd</include>
                        </includes>
                    </fileset>
                </schema>
                <schema>
                    <dependencyResource>
                        <groupId>AgroupID</groupId>
                        <artifactId>AartifactID</artifactId>
                        <resource>xsd/A.xsd</resource>
                    </dependencyResource>
                </schema>
            </schemas>
            <episodes>
                <episode>
                    <groupId>AgroupID</groupId>
                    <artifactId>AartifactID</artifactId>
                </episode>
            </episodes>
            <debug>true</debug>
            <verbose>true</verbose>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
                    <version>0.6.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb2-basics-annotate</artifactId>
                    <version>0.6.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb2-namespace-prefix</artifactId>
                    <version>1.1</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

You must perform a mvn install of project A before the project B

---

Add this plugin to add to source target generated classes

```
          <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-source</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-source</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sources>
                                <source>target/generated-sources/xjc</source>
                            </sources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Remember to perform Maven - update project

Comment: +1 for using the official JAXB plugin.
https://jaxb.java.net/
https://java.net/projects/maven-jaxb2-plugin/pages/Home

Comment: Strange, i work in an architecture complex based on this plugin. See this [link](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/MJIIP/User+Guide#UserGuide-Separateschemacompilation) to separate compilation and [this](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/MJIIP/User+Guide#UserGuide-Resourceentries) to refer a resource.

Comment: I added an example of as it should be :)

Comment: @Puce I am the author of the `maven-jaxb2-plugin` you mention. To be clear, this is NOT an "official" JAXB plugin. I am not an Oracle employee and not affiliated.

Comment: It turns out that I can use <xs:import namespace="http://my_company" schemaLocation="common.xsd" />  in my main.xsd, but episod file seems to be ignored and common classes are generated twice ( in project A and B)

Comment: You must remove schemaLocation="common.xsd" else identify as local source

Comment: @lexicore thanks for the clarifiaction. But at least it's the only one Maven plugin mentioned on the official JAXB homepage: https://jaxb.java.net/

Comment: It generates now, but in target folder. Can I specify it to generate in src/main/generated?

Comment: I added <sources><source>src/main/generated/</source></sources> but it still generate in target folder

Comment: You should only copy <code>build-helper-maven-plugin</code> this plugin in your pom.xml (below my answer).. Let me know

Comment: ? I have this one maven-jaxb2-plugin . Why should I have another plugin with the same executions etc

Comment: The second one adds the classes generated to source. You need of this to work fine everything and use the generated classes.

Comment: Have you perform a maven update project? .. as i say in my answer

Comment: now it created target/generated-sourcex/xjc but I wanted something different. I have src/main/generated and I want that thse generated classes will be placed there, but when I specify  <source>src/main/generated</source> it still create target/generated..

Comment: See the guide  of that plugin [here](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/MJIIP/User+Guide). <generatePackage> is that you needed. Anyway the topic is solved, you were able to resolve all by maven plugins.