# Maven fails compiling generated source on Hudson but works properly from command line

Tags: maven, jaxb, hudson

I have

1. to generate java sources from WSDL
2. and to compile sources

through Maven and Hudson

Here my **pom.xml**

```
[...]
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.6</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>xjc</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <packageName>mypk.monitoring.jmx.bind</packageName>
        <outputDirectory>${basedir}/src/generated-sources</outputDirectory>
        <schemaDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</schemaDirectory>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>add-source</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>add-source</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <sources>
                    <source>${basedir}/src/generated-sources</source>
                </sources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
[...]
```

here the result

```
[artifact:mvn] [INFO] Generating source...
[artifact:mvn] [INFO] parsing a schema...
[artifact:mvn] [INFO] compiling a schema...  
[artifact:mvn] [INFO] mypck/monitoring/jmx/bind/ApplicationRuntimeType.java
[artifact:mvn] [INFO] mypck/monitoring/jmx/bind/ApplicationType.java
[artifact:mvn] [INFO] mypck/monitoring/jmx/bind/ClusterType.java
[artifact:mvn] [INFO] mypck/monitoring/jmx/bind/DomainType.java
[artifact:mvn] [INFO] mypck/monitoring/jmx/bind/EJBType.java
[artifact:mvn] [INFO] mypck/monitoring/jmx/bind/JDBCDataSourceType.java
[artifact:mvn] [INFO] mypck/monitoring/jmx/bind/JDBCOracleDataSourceType.java
[artifact:mvn] [INFO] mypck/monitoring/jmx/bind/JMSModuleType.java
[artifact:mvn] [INFO] mypck/monitoring/jmx/bind/JMSServerType.java
[artifact:mvn] [INFO] mypck/monitoring/jmx/bind/JMSType.java
[artifact:mvn] [INFO] mypck/monitoring/jmx/bind/MDBType.java
[artifact:mvn] [INFO] mypck/monitoring/jmx/bind/ModuleType.java
[artifact:mvn] [INFO] mypck/monitoring/jmx/bind/ObjectFactory.java
[artifact:mvn] [INFO] mypck/monitoring/jmx/bind/ObjectType.java
[artifact:mvn] [INFO] mypck/monitoring/jmx/bind/ProbesType.java
[artifact:mvn] [INFO] mypck/monitoring/jmx/bind/QueueType.java
[artifact:mvn] [INFO] mypck/monitoring/jmx/bind/ResourceType.java
[artifact:mvn] [INFO] mypck/monitoring/jmx/bind/ServerType.java
[artifact:mvn] [INFO] mypck/monitoring/jmx/bind/TypeType.java
[artifact:mvn] [INFO] mypck/monitoring/jmx/bind/WorkManagerType.java
[artifact:mvn] [INFO] mypck/monitoring/jmx/bind/package-info.java
[artifact:mvn] [INFO]
```

---THE SOURCES ARE GENERATED---

```
[artifact:mvn] [INFO] --- build-helper-maven-plugin:1.8:add-source (add-source) @ scol-krn-jmxprobe-jar ---
[artifact:mvn] [INFO] Source directory: /ws/scol-krn-jmxprobe-jar/src/generated-sources added.
[artifact:mvn] [INFO] 
[artifact:mvn] [INFO] --- jaxb2-maven-plugin:1.3:xjc (default) @ scol-krn-jmxprobe-jar ---
[artifact:mvn] [INFO] No changes detected in schema or binding files, skipping source generation.
[artifact:mvn] [INFO] 
[artifact:mvn] [INFO] --- build-helper-maven-plugin:1.8:add-source (add-source) @ scol-krn-jmxprobe-jar ---
[artifact:mvn] [INFO] Source directory: /ws/scol-krn-jmxprobe-jar/src/generated-sources added.
```

---THE SOURCES DIRECTORY IS ADDED-----

```
[artifact:mvn] [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[artifact:mvn] [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] [...] MDBVisitor.java:[64,7] error: cannot find symbol
[artifact:mvn] 
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR]  variable mdb of type MDBType
[artifact:mvn] [...] MDBVisitor.java:[72,7] error: cannot find symbol
```

**Maven version 3.1.2.**
from command line works properly!!!

Comment: try [this configuration](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26011623/3364187), I solved this topic by the same plugins.

Comment: thanks, but didn't solve...I d not uderstand the problem

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line

```
<outputDirectory>${basedir}/src/generated-sources</outputDirectory>
```

remove the plugin

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>add-source</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>add-source</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <sources>
                    <source>${basedir}/src/generated-sources</source>
                </sources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

sometime Hudson is not able to add custom sources....I don't know why!